# No option for Image upload from the computer in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ckeditor

I have downloaded the `CK Editor` from [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) site. There are many features available on their site which works properly when I integrated into my site.

But,

> there is no feature available to upload image from the local computer.

Is there any easiest way to integrate this. The below is the way, I implemented the code.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CKEditor.NET" Namespace="CKEditor.NET" TagPrefix="CKEditor" %>
```

AND

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="txtPagedesc" BasePath="/ckeditor/" runat="server">
                                            </CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
```

Please help

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

These documents might help you.

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browse_upload
 http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_file_upload

Comment: how to integrate that in my existing one ?

Comment: You need to work on your ckeditor config file.To work with any third party service, it requires to read their documentation first for what they are providing and how to integrate. Please go through the first link i gave. every thing is described in that link with different examples. you can checkout the demo from http://cksource.com/ckfinder/demo#ckeditor. also see the link how it works:  http://screencast.com/t/4FOrXmXttx6

Comment: I am not able to integrate that, I have `config.js` file in my project which is related to ckeditor, My js code is something like this `CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
 // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
 // config.language = 'fr';
 // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
};`

Comment: can you please show the screen short of your ckeditor how it looks?

Comment: Can you please show your updated code also? And what it says when you click on Advanced tab?

Comment: I have added the code in the question, what else code do you want ? which file code ??

Comment: I dont have any option of browsing on `Advanced tab`

Comment: Any help related to this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. CKEditor doesn't have feature to upload image directly from local computer. But I think this should be help you :

https://github.com/hendcorp/ckeditor-img-upload

It uses Bootstrap, jQuery and PHP to create simple pop up (modals) to upload images directly from local computer and we just need to click uploaded image to insert into CKEditor. I hope it can help.

Comment: can you let me know how to go step by step..!